# return a dynamically allocated array of the same length but with the elements in the reverse order

Tags: c++, arrays

> Write a function, reverseArray, that when passed an int array of length greater than 0 will return a dynamically allocated array of the same length but with the elements in the reverse order. For example, if passed the array, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} the function would return the array {0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}.

Below is my code, but there is a bug in it.

This is my output.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
4113
6
5
4
3
2
1
0x7fffe697ceb0
```

The 4113 and address are provided by the compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int * readNumbers() {

    int * a = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        int x;
        cin >> x;
        a[i] = x;

    }
    // a++;
    return a;
    delete[] a;
}

int *reverseArray(int *numbers1,int length) {
    for (int i = length; i >=0; i--) {
        cout << numbers1[i] << endl;
    }
    return numbers1;
    delete [] numbers1;
}



int main() {
    int *arr1 = readNumbers();

    cout << reverseArray(arr1,6) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete [] numbers1;` in reverseArray() does nothing. Thankfully. If it was before the return it would have been a serious bug. Same goes for `delete[] a;`  If you used some other language in the past that had new and delete the behavior of these may be different. There is no garbage collection in c++ and you can't and don't want to free the same allocation multiple times.

Comment: Yes, thanks. but when I comment delete [] numbers1; and delete[] a; The bug is still here. i have no idea why 4113 and a address appeared on my output

Comment: That bug is caused by `int i = length`. The valid indices of the numbers1 dynamic array are 0 .. length -1 or 0 to 5. numbers1[6] is one past the end of the array.

Comment: Discuss what `cout << reverseArray(arr1,6) << endl;` does [with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Instead of faffing around with operators `new` and `delete` (which you are using incorrectly - which is easy to do), use `std::vector<int>` instead (which is harder to misuse accidentally).  A vector of int can be dynamically resized (if you follow the rules, naturally) and manages itself (no chance of forgetting to release).  And, once you have data in a vector, call it `x` say, you can obtain a reversed version using `std::vector<int> x_reversed(x); std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());`   (where the algorithm `reverse()` comes from standard header `<algorithm>`). Printing elements is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I think there may have been an issue with your wording. Assuming you want your function just to *print* the reverse of a passed array, you're off to a good start.

One issue is what was said in the comments: your for loop is indexing past your array. When you type `int * a = new int[6];` you are creating a pointer 'a' which points to a location in memory. Since you chose size 6, the appropriate amount of memory is allocated. If you happen to index outside of that range, you will end up pointing to a random spot in memory, not allocated for your array. Hence why you are getting a weird number '4113'.

A fix for this could be:

`int i = length` changed to `int i = length-1`

Another issue is that your function returns an integer pointer, and you are trying to cout this pointer. As another commenter said, you have to think about what this does. If you try this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

    cout << arr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

your output would be something like 0xff09ba. This represents the *location* of the start of the array in memory. If you change `arr` to `(arr + 1)` you will get the location of the second index of the array.

So when you type `cout << reverseArray(arr1,6) << endl;` you are really just printing out the *location* of numbers1 in memory. This is why you are getting '0x7fffe697ceb0' in your output. To fix this, simply make your function

```
void reverseArray(int *numbers1,int length) {
    for (int i = length; i >=0; i--) {
        cout << numbers1[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

and change your main to:

```
int main() {
    int *arr1 = readNumbers();

    reverseArray(arr1,6);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you actually want to *return* this array, you would need to create a new array which holds the reverse numbers and then return that. An example of a function that does that is:

```
int* reverseArray(int *numbers1,int length) {
    int j = 0;
    int *numbers2 = new int[length];

    for (int i = length-1; i >=0; i--) {
        numbers2[j] = numbers1[i];
        j++;
    }

    return numbers2;
}
```

There are probably better ways to do this, but this is just one solution. Regardless, you should always be careful when allocating memory yourself.